# Visual Studio Code - Ctrl+Backspace not working in Integrated Terminal

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

In the terminal (PowerShell) in `Visual Studio Code`, I'm trying to hit `Ctrl+Backspace` to delete last word, but it just adds `^W` to end of the line, any ideas how to fix this? It works fine outside Visual Studio Code in PowerShell.

Answer (score 13):

`ctrl+backspace` is somehow mapped to `ctrl+w` in vscode integrated terminal (possibly a bug) and now we need to set `ctrl+w` binding to delete the word explicitly. weird right?

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+w' -Function BackwardKillWord
```

Note that this'll work for the current terminal session only.

---

To make this behaviour persistent, you can set it in profile `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` file. Create the file if it doesn't exist in your powershell *version* folder.

```
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

write at the top

```
if ($env:TERM_PROGRAM -eq "vscode") {
  Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'Ctrl+w' -Function BackwardKillWord
}
```

---

See more: [Power up your PowerShell](https://gourav.io/blog/powershell)

Keybinding references:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/powershell/module/psreadline/Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler?view=powershell-5.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-5.0

Comment: I see exceptions: 'Set-PSReadLineOption' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Tried both windows cmd and powershell but returned the same error.

Comment: You can run `$profile` to see where the location of the `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` file should be.

Comment: The location of the Power Shell profile file can vary and depends on whether the settings should apply for all users/hosts or only the current one. For the current user it is enough to create one in `$HOME\Documents\PowerShell`. See [this link for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3). (PS: There it is also said that a VS Code specific profile can be used, but in my test VS Code did not recognize it.)

Answer (score 4):

It was showing `^W` when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Just run this command in the vscode console

`Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Emacs`

NOW IT WORKS!

Comment: This setting will stop `ctrl + arrow key` from letting you jump through words.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the latest comment https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68167 I have modified JerryGoyal's answer so we don't have to modify bindings:

Put the following at the top of your `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` config file (type `$profile` in the terminal to find it, you might have to create one if it doesn't exist already)

```
if ($env:TERM_PROGRAM -eq "vscode") {
  Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Emacs
}
```

This works for me (vscode 1.43)

Comment: This may have unintended consequences. [The available modes are Windows, Emacs, and Vi, of which Windows is the default.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7.2) Emacs and Vi may introduce strange keyboard shortcuts that the typical Windows user may be unaccustomed to.

Comment: @DharmaTurtle Yes, with this setting now using ctrl to jump through words does not work.

Answer (score 2):

**Add this to `keybindings.json` in vs code**

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+backspace",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "when": "terminalFocus",
    "args": { "text": "\u0008" }
  },
```

Comment: This fails to delete word :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue that is being tracked: see [workbench.action.terminal.deleteWordLeft Doesn't Work, Outputs ^W](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/59071).

Works fine for me in git bash terminal but not powershell as of vscode 1.36.

---

vscode v1.45 made some changes to these terminal commands, like `deleteWordLeft`.  Does Ctrl+Backspace work better for you now?

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#removal-of-several-prompt-related-commands

Comment: that issue is not being resolved in VScode community - they ignored it..

Comment: I've see it's being ignored too. That's sad. A very much pain in daily use.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode 1.48 (July2020) might help.
[Issue 98404](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98404) does allow <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> to delete entire word in `cmd.exe`, which could work for a powershell session too.

See [PR 98494](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/98494):

Before (when it was *not* working):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/39542938/82770461-bca2ce00-9e06-11ea-8f76-1b168cf03e3d.gif]

After (working):

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/39542938/82770356-430ae000-9e06-11ea-9229-288667544326.gif]

Answer (score 0):

Check you keybindings in your settings to be sure it is still set.

I have had some oddities with keybindings getting removed / changed when adding a new extension or an update. You may just need to add it back.

[Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Of course VSCode and PowerShell are two different environments. If you split your terminal window (I do this all the time for my own work use case), you will end up with the VSChost and the standard consolehost and you'll see that though you are in VSCode, they behave differently.

If you have not done so, you may want to customize you VSCode profile which is what the integrated console will read, where as the consolehost will read your PowerShell console profile not you ISE profile.

Comment: I added this in key bindings but didn't work: {"key": "ctrl+backspace", "command":"workbench.action.terminal.deleteWordLeft"}

Answer (score 0):

To add to JerryGoyal answer:

If you have difficulties finding profile folder and/or making it works. Here's what helped me.

1. I created folder c:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\
2. Put Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 there
3. Powershell than tells you about security problems. You have to allow this by running powershell as admin.
4. Than type Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned.
5. Answer Y(yes). This is obviously at your own risk!